# Filtering binlogs from Debezium?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

As titled, I used Debezium and tried to filter out the latest record by time from binlogs before entering the Kafka topic. Does anyone know it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate the use case a bit more in detail

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G , because I want to receivce the lastest event. However, I got the whole events from binlogs. I am not sure whether It should be adjusted the offset in topic or something to do with ?